What has to be sent as Bluetooth LE indication acknowledgement
My application uses the TI Bluetopia stack. This stack runs in user space and uses the HCI without and kernel driver.
The peripherial device sends the data by indication. But after a few data sets the connection is closed. The data are provided as part of an event, so no buffer should overrun or any other ressource should go out of space.
In the past everything runs fine with notification. So my assumtion is, that the indication confirmation/acknowledgement is missing. What do I have to send to the bluetooth server to confirm the indication?

Generally speaking, indication confirmation/acknowledgement are handled by the stack under the hood. However, if this is not the case with the Bluetopia stack, you need to look for an event that probably has "ATT" and "confirm" or "ack" in the name. I found the command ATT_HandleValueCfm from the TI documentation, but I am not sure if this is specific to the Bluetopia stack. You can also check for the disconnect reason (which is a value that should be generated as part of the HCI disconnection event) to get a better idea why the disconnection is happening.
